# Is Selenium platform specific?

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

Is Selenium paltform specific. If yes then how can I develop a cross-platform specific application with it by first identifying the platform and then call the platform-specific selenium routines.

Comment: When you ask platform specific are you asking in the term of recording tests or executing tests?

Comment: ... or even more detailed. In terms of executing test code towards some server, running the Selenium server and the browser (Selenium RC), or recording tests with Selenium IDE.

Comment: Please explain your question better. Are you using Selenium RC or IDE?
Which programming language (in case you're using RC).
Which platform specific code would you want to run?

Answer (score 3):

The IDE is a firefox plugin, but you can develop tests in multiple languages, which run on and against multiple platforms (including multiple browsers). Not really sure what you're trying to accomplish, but hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 3):

Selenium is platform independent. This is because you run a Selenium RC server (which is a java application and hence can be run on any platform). Then you send selenese commands to the server which controls the testing activity on the browser. To send the selenese commands you can use any language (such as Java, PHP, Ruby etc). Now this again does not limit you in any way to a certain OS.

If you are using the Firefox plugin IDE to run the test cases then of course the platforms supported would be limited to platforms supported by Firefox.

Hope that answers.

Answer (score 1):

I may be misunderstanding your question, but:

With Selenium RC (or Grid, more specifically), you can specify what platform you want your test to run on. Each node registers with the hub under a particular platform, and each test's DesiredCapabilities can request a platform.

As the other answers have stated, Selenium itself is platform independent but you can run your tests on a by-platform by-browser basis. Either way, the tests (in theory) should look the same and use the same native Selenium commands.

Answer (score 0):

I am not so familiar with Selenium, but it looks to me that it works almost everywhere where you can install Firefox 2+.

[Platforms Supported by Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/about/platforms.html#operating-systems)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Selenium for a project that runs under Windows and Ubuntu. The only platform specific code is for starting the environment where it executes (headless X server under Ubuntu) and starting the Selenium jar file. The rest is all platform independent. I don't know if this will also work as smoothly when you try to use different browsers (I'm using Firefox on both platforms).